# Perl:Access values of hash inside a hash

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures, hash-of-hashes, perl-hash

I have just picked up Perl. 
I have a little confusion with accessing hash values. Below is the code where I am trying to access the values of a hash inside a hash. 
Since am using a simple text editor to code, I am not able to figure out what can be the problem. Please help

```
my %box = (
    Milk => {
        A => 5,
        B => 10,
        C => 20,
    },
    Chocolate => {
        AB => 10,
        BC => 25,
        CD => 40,
    },
);

foreach my $box_key(keys %box) {
    foreach my $inside_key (keys %box{box_key})
    print "$box_key"."_$inside_key""is for rupees $box{box_key}{inside_key}";
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ikegami has explained it very well and I feel that you are still missing something in your code that's why you are having a problem, try the below code, hope it helps you.

```
my %box = (
    Milk => {
        A => 5,
        B => 10,
        C => 20,
    },
    Chocolate => {
        AB => 10,
        BC => 25,
        CD => 40,
    },
);

foreach my $box_key(keys %box) {
    foreach my $inside_key (keys $box{$box_key}) {
      print "${box_key}_$inside_key is for rupees $box{$box_key}{$inside_key}\n";

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Chocolate_CD is for rupees 40
Chocolate_BC is for rupees 25
Chocolate_AB is for rupees 10
Milk_A is for rupees 5
Milk_C is for rupees 20
Milk_B is for rupees 10
```

Comment: regarding style it's better to write `print $box_key, "_", $inside_key, " .."` or `print "${box_key}_$inside_key .."`

Comment: You really should not ever give the undereferenced-argument version of keys: that’s a syntax error under most versions of perl.

Comment: What did you do different from my post? You seem to have merely copied my code except you changed "for" to "foreach"

Answer (score 3):

If the syntax is

```
keys %hash
```

for a hash, it's

```
keys %{ ... }
```

for a hash reference. In this case, the reference is stored in `$box{$box_key}`, so you'd use

```
keys %{ $box{$box_key} }
```

---

Also, you're accessing elements named `box_key` and `inside_key` in a couple of places where you actually want the elements named by `$box_key` and `$inside_key`.

---

Finally, you can use curlies around variable names to instruct Perl where the variable name ends.

---

```
for my $box_key (keys %box) {
   for my $inside_key (keys %{ $box{$box_key} }) {
      print "${box_key}_$inside_key is for rupees $box{$box_key}{$inside_key}\n";
   }
}
```