# hash inside hash, fails to fetch data

Tags: perl

I try to iterate through hash that contains other hashes.

I get error:

> Global symbol "%arch_" requires explicit package name

Here is a code:

```
my %ARCH_CODES = (
    armv7  => {id  => 102, desc => "aaaaaa"},
    i386   => {id  => 103, desc => "bbbbbb"},
    x86_64 => {id  => 104, desc => "cccccc"},
    arm64  => {id  => 105, desc => "dddddd"}
);

sub af_exit
{
    my %_error = @_;
    writeLogAndPrint($_error{'id'});
    exit($_error{'id'});
}
```

So I want to run in loop on `armv7`, `i386` and so on and send hash map to `af_exit`

```
for my $arch_ (keys %ARCH_CODES) {
       foo($ARCH_CODES{$arch_}); 
       # tried foo(%{ $ARCH_CODES{$arch_} } ) 
    }
```

The problem happens in `foo` method:

```
sub foo
{
   my %arch = @_; # here I get an ERROR: Global symbol "%arch_" requires explicit package name
     my $res = runCommand("file zzz | grep \"$arch{id})\"");
     af_exit($ARCH_CODES{$arch});
   }
}
```

The second problem is `af_exit` should receive **hash** so I need somehow convert `$ARCH_CODES{$arch}` to hash and not scalar

I tried to make similar to [this answer: Perl:Access values of hash inside a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036955/perlaccess-values-of-hash-inside-a-hash) but get the same error

Any ideas?

Comment: `$ARCH_CODES{$arch_}` is a hash reference which contains the value => `{id  => 102, desc => "aaaaaa"}` and you could use `my $arch = @_` to get the hash reference and then access this hash reference like `foreach my $keys ( keys %$arch )`

Comment: @AbhiNickz but in this case I cannot use `af_exit($ARCH_CODES{$arch});`

Comment: You can use `af_exit($arch);` which will send the `hash` reference to the sub and then you can use that again like `my $_error = @_;`

Comment: Change `my %_error = @_;` to `my %_error = %{$_[0]};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `foo` is getting a hashref

```
foo( $ARCH_CODES{$arch_} );
```

since values of `%ARCH_CODES` are hash references, while it expects a hash

```
sub foo
{
    my %arch = @_;
    # ...
}
```

So you are attempting to assign a list with a single scalar (hashref) to a hash.  For this you'd get a warning `Odd number of elements in hash assignment` if you had warnings on, which would directly lead you to the error.

Change `foo` so that it takes that scalar

```
my ($rarch) = @_;
```

and then either use the reference `$rarch`, or make a new hash in the sub, `my %arch = %$rarch`, and keep the rest of the function's code unchanged.

Or you can pass the hash to the function, `foo( %{$ARCH_CODES{$arch_}} )` and the rest of the code stays as it is. In general, I prefer to pass long lists and complex data structures by reference.

When you work with the reference (`$rarch`) any changes to it change the data it is the reference of. This allows us to change caller's data efficiently. On the other hand, when you de-reference it in the sub you get a local copy. This is safer since accidental changes to it (errors) cannot affect the caller.

Please *always* `use warnings;`

---

The same error is repeated when you call `af_exit`, passing it a hashref

```
af_exit($ARCH_CODES{$arch});
```

while it expects a hash

```
sub af_exit
{
     my %_error = @_;
```

Correct it the same way as above.

Comment: @snaggs I edited the answer (adding two other ways), please let me know if more would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar way using pass by reference. Hope you find it useful.

A couple of points:

1. In your foreach loop and sub foo, you are passing a scalar and not a hash reference.
2. You can also use shift to receive input at the subroutine and then de-reference the variable to retrieve the value.

In the sample code below, in subroutine foo, I am performing dummy operation to pass the hash map to af_exit, only when id is either 102 or 104, just as an example.

Here I have turned off the Data::Dumper output and I am also not printing the reference type of value being received by the subroutines. We will see that later.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings  ;
use Data::Dumper ;

my %ARCH_CODES = (
    armv7  => {id  => 102, desc => "aaaaaa"},
    i386   => {id  => 103, desc => "bbbbbb"},
    x86_64 => {id  => 104, desc => "cccccc"},
    arm64  => {id  => 105, desc => "dddddd"}
);

sub af_exit
{
        my $error = shift ;
        my $ref = ref $error ;
        #print "af_exit got variable which is of type $ref. Below is the Data Dumper output\n" ;
        #print Dumper $error ;
        print "${$error}{'id'}\n" ;
        #exit($$error{'id'});
        print "af_exit will perform exit on \[$$error{'id'}\]\n" ;
}

sub foo
{
        my $arch = shift ;
        my $ref = ref $arch ;
        #print "af_exit got variable which is of type $ref. Below is the Data Dumper output\n" ;
        #print Dumper $arch ;
        #my $res = runCommand("file zzz | grep \"$arch{id})\"");
        if ($$arch{id} == 102 || $$arch{id} == 104)
        {

                af_exit(\%$arch);
        }
}

for my $arch_ (keys %ARCH_CODES)
{
       foo(\%{$ARCH_CODES{$arch_}}) ;
}
```

Result:

```
%_04:04:54|root@[goat]:/home/ec2-user/cpp/study/temp> ./test
104
af_exit will perform exit on [104]
102
af_exit will perform exit on [102]
%_04:04:56|root@[goat]:/home/ec2-user/cpp/study/temp>
```

You can always use Data::Dumper and ref to show you exactly what is being passed around. See the Result below again with the Dumper and reference output on.

```
%_04:09:19|root@[goat]:/home/ec2-user/cpp/study/temp> ./test
af_exit got variable which is of type HASH. Below is the Data Dumper output
$VAR1 = {
          'desc' => 'cccccc',
          'id' => 104
        };
af_exit got variable which is of type HASH. Below is the Data Dumper output
$VAR1 = {
          'desc' => 'cccccc',
          'id' => 104
        };
104
af_exit will perform exit on [104]
af_exit got variable which is of type HASH. Below is the Data Dumper output
$VAR1 = {
          'desc' => 'dddddd',
          'id' => 105
        };
af_exit got variable which is of type HASH. Below is the Data Dumper output
$VAR1 = {
          'desc' => 'aaaaaa',
          'id' => 102
        };
af_exit got variable which is of type HASH. Below is the Data Dumper output
$VAR1 = {
          'desc' => 'aaaaaa',
          'id' => 102
        };
102
af_exit will perform exit on [102]
af_exit got variable which is of type HASH. Below is the Data Dumper output
$VAR1 = {
          'desc' => 'bbbbbb',
          'id' => 103
        };
%_04:09:21|root@[goat]:/home/ec2-user/cpp/study/temp>
```